# Ubuntu shows "resolving host" but Android is able to instantly access internet on the same network

Tags: networking, dns

I am connected to my home wifi network. I have this constant problem with my laptop which runs Ubuntu 14.04 currently. Very often, while accessing the internet, I can see the web pages timing out or Google Chrome and Firefox showing "Resolving ..." at the bottom.

However, my Android phone (Nexus 5), can instantly access the internet on the same network ( mobile data disabled).

How do I resolve this issue?

```
 sudo dhclient wlan0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists


     cat /etc/resolv.conf
    # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
    #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
    nameserver 127.0.1.1
    nameserver 8.8.8.8


    ls -lrt /etc/resolv.conf
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Apr 15 01:08 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

Here are some traceroute results.The results were obtained within 30 seconds of each other

**Phone**

-

```
-- 16-Apr-2015 1:09:08 pm
--- IP (wlan0) xxxxxxx
--- IP (wlan0) x.x.x.x
--- Connection: WIFI

Trace to gsmarena.com

1 - 192.168.1.1
2 -
3 - 59.180.212.6
      triband-del-59.180.212.6.bol.net.in
4 - 59.180.210.194
      triband-del-59.180.210.194.bol.net.in
5 - 115.254.111.158
6 - 115.255.252.57
7 - 62.216.147.73
8 - 85.95.26.233
      xe-0-1-1.0.pjr03.ldn001.flagtel.com
9 - 85.95.25.22
      ge-5-0-0.0.ejr01.ams001.flagtel.com
10 - 80.249.209.55
      amsix-gw.hetzner.de
11 - 213.239.203.157
      core1.hetzner.de
12 - 213.239.245.217
      core21.hetzner.de
13 - 213.239.245.242
      juniper4.rz20.hetzner.de
14 - 213.239.203.76
      hos-tr3.ex3k24.rz20.hetzner.de
15 - 148.251.77.209
      www.gsmarena.com
```

**Laptop**

```
flex2:~$ traceroute www.gsmarena.com
www.gsmarena.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `www.gsmarena.com' on position 1 (argc 1)
```

Comment: Why are you using Google's DNS rather than using your ISP provided one? What name server your phone uses ?

Comment: @heemayl, that's because my ISP has the worst DNS. Doesnt resolve anything. BTW, google's nameserver is also set in the router so either way its using the Google DNS

Comment: Ok, lets get some idea..run `time host yahoo.com >/dev/null` with `yahoo.com` replaced by any hostname that is taking too much time to be resolved..this will give us ideas about time being taken in resolving..

Comment: `time host gmail.com > /dev/null

real 0m10.066s
user 0m0.004s
sys 0m0.004s`

Comment: `time host drive.google.com > /dev/null

real 0m10.010s
user 0m0.008s
sys 0m0.000s
`

Comment: Ooops..that is some time..lets try it disabling DNSmasq of NetworkManager..run `sudo sed -i.bak '/^dns=dnsmasq$/s/^/#/' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and then `sudo service network-manager restart` ..now try `host` command and browsing..

Comment: its making the internet connectivity all the more slow